# Return all pairs from a list of integers that contributes to a given sum

Tags: java, programming-challenge, k-sum

> Given a list of integers return all the pairs that makes up to a given
>   target sum.
>
> input: `{2, 7, 11, 15, -2}`  target sum: `9`
>
> This should return all the pairs i.e `{-2,11} and {7,2}`.
>
> If there are duplicates that form the same pair, they should not be
>   returned.

Here is the code for this problem - would be great to know how this can be refactored for improvement.

```
   public class TwoSum {
    static class Pair {
        int x, y;

        public Pair(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o == null) {
                return false;
            }

            if (o instanceof Pair) {
                Pair other = (Pair) o;
                if (other.x == this.x && other.y == this.y) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringBuilder().append("{").append(this.x).append(",").append(this.y).append("}").toString();
        }
    }

    public static Set<Pair> findPairs(int inputs[], int targetSum) {
        Set<Pair> results = new HashSet<>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int number : inputs) {
            int remainingSum = targetSum - number;

            if (map.containsKey(number)) {
                results.add(new Pair(number, map.get(number)));
            } else {
                map.put(remainingSum, number);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

To invoke this code:

```
System.out.println(TwoSum.findPairs(new int[]{2, 7, 11, 15, -2}, 9));
```

This would print:

```
[{-2,11}, {7,2}]
```

Code here:

https://github.com/Ramblers-Code/CodeKata/blob/master/src/main/java/kata/array/TwoSum.java

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question after answers have been submitted, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing the comments here is the answer:

Github: https://github.com/Ramblers-Code/CodeKata/blob/master/src/main/java/kata/array/TwoSum.java#L8

```
static class Pair {
        final int x, y;

        public Pair(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof Pair) {
                Pair other = (Pair) o;
                return other.x == this.x && other.y == this.y;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(x, y);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringBuilder("{").append(this.x).append(",").append(this.y).append("}").toString();
        }
    }

    public static Set<Pair> findPairs(int inputs[], int targetSum) {
        Set<Pair> results = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Integer> visited = new HashSet<>();

        for (int number : inputs) {
            int complement = targetSum - number;

            if (visited.contains(number)) {
                results.add(new Pair(number, complement));
            } else {

                visited.add(complement);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

- I see that you are overriding `Object.equals(Object)` without overriding `Object.hashCode()`. By doing this, you violate the contract of `Object.hashCode()` (see the last paragraph in the description of [`Object.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)). In fact, the `HashSet<Pair>` created in your `findPairs` method might not operate properly due to this.
- Since the values of `x` and `y` of a `Pair` instance never change, you could make `x` and `y` `final`, thereby making `Pair` an immutable class and preventing accidental tampering with the values of `x` and `y`.
- I don't know if you've considered this, but your code would treat `{2,3}` and `{3,2}` as two distinct pairs. Due to how the `findPairs` method works, it doesn't matter, since it will never create two pairs that only differ in the order of the two numbers, but I thought I'd point it out in case you were not aware of that.
- The null check in `Pair.equals(Object)` is redundant, since `null instanceof X`, with `X` being the name of class, will always return `false`.
- ```java
  if (o instanceof Pair) {
      Pair other = (Pair) o;
      if (other.x == this.x && other.y == this.y) {
          return true;
      }
  }
  return false;
  ```

  can be written more concise as:

  ```java
  if (o instanceof Pair) {
      Pair other = (Pair) o;
      return other.x == this.x && other.y == this.y;
  }
  return false;
  ```
- ```java
  new StringBuilder().append("{")
  ```

  can also be shortened:

  ```java
  new StringBuilder("{")
  ```
- You don't actually need a `Map<Integer, Integer>` in `findPairs`. The mapping of integers to their complement serves no purpose, because the complement of an integer can be simply calculated by subtracting it from the target sum. A `Set<Integer>` would suffice, since you just use the map to determine whether the complement of a number has already appeared in the sequence of numbers. So `findPairs` can be re-written as:

  ```java
  public static Set<Pair> findPairs(int inputs[], int targetSum) {
      Set<Pair> results = new HashSet<>();
      Set<Integer> pastNumbers = new HashSet<>();

      for (int number : inputs) {
          int remainingSum = targetSum - number;

          if (pastNumbers.contains(remainingSum)) {
              results.add(new Pair(number, remainingSum));
          } else {
              pastNumbers.add(number);
          }
      }
      return results;
  }
  ```

Comment: I actually updated the equals in the GitHub code but forgot to paste back the code sample. Good catch - appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As [Stingy says](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/190127/67881) your `Pair` should make `x` and `y` final and override `hashCode()`. Also, the `StringBuilder` in `toString()` is overkill -- it's hard to read and doesn't gain you anything in performance over simple concatenation ([the compiler will replace simple concatenation with `StringBuilder` anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1532499/27358)). In this case I might even use `String.format`. (If you start with simple concatenation, your IDE will probably offer a quick-fix.)

When you're iterating over a plural, convention is for the loop variable to be the singular. So `inputs`  `input`, not `number`.

Right now `remainingSum` is only used in the `else` case, which suggests it should be inside the `else` block -- but read on:

It's not at all clear what the map is for; consider a more meaningful variable name than `map`. (In fact it's so unclear it's not even obvious at first glance whether the code is correct. You should almost never name a map `map`, a set `set`, etc.)

Stingy is probably right that you don't even really want/need a map, just a set, which (if you're going to use it the way you're using the map) I would call something like `expected`. Also, `remainingSum` is not a sum, and should be something like `complement`.

That gets us as far as:

```
Set<Pair> results = new HashSet<>();
Set<Integer> expected = new HashSet<>();

for (int input : inputs) {
  int complement = targetSum - input;

  if (expected.contains(input)) {
    results.add(new Pair(input, complement));
  } else {
    expected.add(complement);
  }
}
return results;
```

-- so we now have a reason for `complement` (formerly `remainingSum`) to be outside the `if`/`else` block.

Personally, I think the algorithm is still a little muddy and hard to explain, and it would be more clear if, as in Stingy's version, you stored the visited numbers (`input`, formerly `number`) instead of the numbers-that-would-indicate-a-success-if-we-should-visit-them-later (`complement`, formerly `remainingSum`).

Comment: But in my proposed code, `pastNumbers` _is_ a set of the numbers that have already been visited … (except the numbers whose complement has been visited before them)

Comment: @Stingy You're right, sorry, I misread. I'll edit that part of my answer.

Comment: @DavidMoles appreciate your feedback - but its probably also depends on the taste.  I actually find remainingSum better as it clearly describes what we are looking for i.e. if the remainingSum is there, viola, we got our pair. Also sure naming it as map does not make sense, but not so sure about `expected` name either. On the other hand, I think overall sting's code rocks.

Comment: @Exploring It's Code Review Stack Exchange. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` I agree that `expected` is still less than obvious, but that's partly a factor of the algorithm. If you want to use Stingy's algorithm, I'd call it `visited`. The `remainingSum` name on the other hand is actively misleading — it's neither a remainder, nor a sum. I wouldn't let that go into production at my day job, and I don't think anyone on my team would either. But it's your code.

Comment: @DavidMoles yeah - it depends on the view, so lets not get over opinionated :-).